# trying to embed a PPSSignatureView object

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, opengl-es, glkview

I am trying to implement this class so that I can [capture a signature](https://github.com/jharwig/PPSSignatureView) in my app:

```
PPSSignatureView *sign = [[PPSSignatureView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 500, 300)];
GLKViewController *glkView = [[GLKViewController alloc] init];
glkView.view = sign;
[self.view addSubview:glkView.view];
```

I've not worked with any openGL components before, so I'm not sure if I'm setting this up properly.

(PPSSignatureView is a subclass of GLKView)

Comment: it's just not appearing in my view. I can only get it to work when i create a GLKView in storyboard and re-class it as PPSSignatureView. How can I do this programmatically?

Comment: just used a xib in the end

Answer (score 5):

Try to use 'initWithFrame:context' instead of initWithFrame:, see the code below:

```
EAGLContext *context = [EAGLContext alloc]initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];
PPSSignatureView *sign = [[PPSSignatureView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 500, 300) context:context];
```

It works for me, hope it helps!

Comment: This worked for me, thank you. However I noticed that **EAGLContext** needs to be cleared before called for a second time. As a result I found it works more then once when I put `[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:nil]` before the context declaration.

Comment: Well, I notice that in the PPSSignatureView's dealloc method, it calls '[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:nil]' itself. I am assuming that you might have allocated more than one instance in memory? Is it a potentially memory leak?

Comment: Thanks, I took a look and if you pass in the context it seams to redecare it... Not sure why or if I understand it.

Comment: Yes, u r right, in the commonInit method, it been allocated again. Actually, if a nil passed as the context var, it works fine! Neither do I understand it...

Answer (score 0):

How about adding it as a child view controller? Here is a sample:

```
[self addChildViewController:gLKVController];
[self.view addSubview:gLKVController.view];
[gLKVController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

I also used the same library and what I did is to embed the whole GLKViewController in a container view, then I resize and position the container view to what I wanted. Much easier for me, no code needed.

[image]